# Show common part of 2 semitransparent objects?

Tags: opengl, testing, transparency, intersection, depth

I'm creating a math app that uses OpenGL to show several geometric 3D shapes. In some cases these shapes intersect and when this happen I want to show the intersecting part of each shape inside the other. As the both shapes are translucent, what I need is more or less something like this:

[image: Perfect intersection]

However, with 2 translucent spheres I get that result instead:

[image: With depth testing]

I know that, to achieve a correct transparency effect, the depth testing should be turned off before the transparent shapes are drawn. However this cause another side effect when a transparent shape is beyond another non transparent shape:

[image: Without depth testing]

So, is there a way to show correctly the intersecting part of 2 volumetric shapes, each inside the other, without breaking the depth testing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So, is there a way to show (…) volumetric shapes

OpenGL (by itself) doesn't know about "volumes". It knows flat triangles, lines and points, which by pure happenstance also may cause rendering side effects like depth sorting by a depth buffer test.

Technically it is possible to chain a series of drawing and stencil buffer operations to perform CSG (*constructive solid geometry*); see ftp://ftp.sgi.com/opengl/contrib/blythe/advanced99/notes/node22.html for details.

However what you want to do is easier implemented through a simple raytracer executed in the fragment shader. Now raytracing by itself is a broad subject and you can fill books on it (actually lots of books have been written on the subject). It's probably best to refer to an example. In this case I refer to the following ShaderToy https://www.shadertoy.com/view/ldS3DW – a slightly stripped down version of that shader draws the kind of intersectional geometry you're interested in:

```
float sphere(vec3 ray, vec3 dir, vec3 center, float radius)
{
    vec3 rc = ray-center;
    float c = dot(rc, rc) - (radius*radius);
    float b = dot(dir, rc);
    float d = b*b - c;
    float t = -b - sqrt(abs(d));
    float st = step(0.0, min(t,d));
    return mix(-1.0, t, st);
}


void mainImage( out vec4 fragColor, in vec2 fragCoord )
{
    vec2 uv = (-1.0 + 2.0*fragCoord.xy / iResolution.xy) * 
        vec2(iResolution.x/iResolution.y, 1.0);

    vec3 ro = vec3(0.0, 0.0, -3.0);
    vec3 rd = normalize(vec3(uv, 1.0));

    vec3 p0 = vec3(0.5, 0.0, 0.0);
    float t0 = sphere(ro, rd, p0, 1.0);

    vec3 p1 = vec3(-0.05, 0.0, 0.0);
    float t1 = sphere(ro, rd, p1, 1.0);

    fragColor = vec4( step(0.0,t0)*step(0.0,t1)*rd, 1.0 );
}
```

Comment: ok, so there is no "magic way" to do that, i.e. by activating or deactivating an option in OpenGL. Good idea to do that in the shader, but in my case I have several shapes beyond the simple spheres, so my shader may become highly more complicated this way. Perhaps the better way for me is finally to use stencil buffers, after all. Anyway, thank you for the answer (and sorry for the mistake about the OpenGL volumes :-) )